# Is there a (built-in) way to reverse a previously executed mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering if there was an easy way to reverse a previously executed mongoose query, or whether I'd have to go the route of creating a way myself - all of my searching seems to suggest the latter.

To clarify, I'm hoping that I could do something like:

```
schema.create(data, (err, docs) => {
    if(err) return err;
    return docs;
});
```

And then call some sort of reverse helper function, like:

```
schema.reverse(0, (err, docs) => {
    if(err) return reject(err);
    resolve(docs);
});
```

Where the first argument to the function is an index into a history of some kind? Of course this is just hypothetical: if anything similar exists, or if you've implemented something like it before, then I'd love to know about it.

Thanks!

Comment: That's what migrations do, https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-migrate

Comment: Generally speaking - no, mongo db it is not git, and does not provide versioning of the data unless you implement it. There are options though: restore from backup, restore from delayed secondary etc.